# Splitting a column that contains a double in R

Tags: r

I am currently working on a project in R and I have a column that receives output from a kmeans model that chooses the mode cluster that a particular store belongs to. Unfortunately there is a tie so one of the instances in the column is getting assigned to two clusters. See example output below. The columns are rownumber, Store, and Cluster, respectively.

```
row  store  cluster
759    759        3
760    760        3
761    761        3
762    762     1, 3
763    763        3
764    764        1
```

I need to break out the 1 from the ,3 and just keep the one in the column.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like this:

```
my_data <- dplyr::data_frame("row" = 759:764, "store" = 759:764, "cluster" = c("3", "3", "3", "1, 3", "3", "1"))
my_data
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]

  row store cluster
1 759   759       3
2 760   760       3
3 761   761       3
4 762   762    1, 3
5 763   763       3
6 764   764       1
my_data$cluster <- my_data$cluster %>% stringr::str_extract("[^,]")
my_data
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]

  row store cluster
1 759   759       3
2 760   760       3
3 761   761       3
4 762   762       1
5 763   763       3
6 764   764       1
```

The line of code that sets `my_data$cluster` tells R to extract everything from a string that is not a comma; once it hits a comma it stops. Since we use `stringr::str_extract` instead of `stringr::str_extract_all`, it only returns the first value.

Answer (score 0):

If the column 'cluster' contains string element, we could do this using `sub` from `base R`.  We match the comma followed by one or more characters until the end of the string and replace it with `''`.

```
df1$cluster <- sub(',.*$', '', df1$cluster)
```

If the column is a `list`, we use `sapply` to extract the first element

```
df1$cluster <-  sapply(df1$cluster, `[`,1)
```